# Type A vs Type AC RCCB

Tags: grounding, electrical, leakage-current

I would like to install an RCCB at the electrical point that will power a few devices that are going to be in my fish pond. Documentation and general info online say that Type AC RCCB can work with resistive loads but will not detect DC leakage currents or is not advisable for DC loads. I'm not sure if the devices in my pond could cause DC leakage current back into the AC line. The devices that will be downstream from this RCCB are an AC powered submerged pond pump (85W), a 12v/16A LED controller with dimmer.

I would also appreciate it if someone could explain what DC leakage current means and in what scenario a type A RCCB will work while type AC won't. Would this be a correct example: if the part of the wiring/circuit that comes in contact with a person (i.e. trigger a leakage current scenario) is the AC (alternating current) carrying part, then both the RCCB types will trip/work and if the part of the wiring/circuit that comes in contact with people is DC, then a Type AC RCCB will not work?

Comment: This belongs on [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: The pond pump is an AC load. The LED load is a relatively heavy (about 200 Watt) DC load.  | BUT there is "something" between the AC mains and the LED - as 12V LEDs do not work on AC mains directly. | Type AC do not trip on DC.  Type A are suited to both. || Leakage current occurs when current on the two supply leads is unequal - because a portion has returned via ground. An AC focused RCCB "looks for" short term imbalance in the go & return current. A DC load has filtering which evens out short term differences. The RCCB must be able to detect the mean loss of current to ground.